# Grouping columns, then deleting values based on null column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am reposting since my last question was poorly worded. I have a table that looks like the following:

```
+------+------+------+------+------------+----------+
| ID 1 | ID 2 | Type | Year | Identified | Multiple |
+------+------+------+------+------------+----------+
|  100 |   10 | A    | 2018 |         12 |          |
|  100 |   11 | B    | 2019 |            | multiple |
|  100 |   12 | C    | 2019 |            | multiple |
|  100 |   13 | D    | 2019 |            |          |
|  200 |   10 | A    | 2018 |            |          |
|  200 |   11 | B    | 2019 |            | multiple |
|  200 |   12 | C    | 2019 |            | multiple |
|  200 |   13 | D    | 2019 |            |          |
+------+------+------+------+------------+----------+
```

I am trying to delete the "multiple" strings inside the "Multiple" column where the `ID` group does not have a `Identified` value. For example, the first group of `ID 1 == 100` contains a not-null `Identified` value so we can leave the "multiple" values. However, the `ID 1 == 200` group has no `Identified` values, so I would like to remove the "multiple" values that appear in this group, giving us the following dataframe.

```
+------+------+------+------+------------+----------+
| ID 1 | ID 2 | Type | Year | Identified | Multiple |
+------+------+------+------+------------+----------+
|  100 |   10 | A    | 2018 |         12 |          |
|  100 |   11 | B    | 2019 |            | multiple |
|  100 |   12 | C    | 2019 |            | multiple |
|  100 |   13 | D    | 2019 |            |          |
|  200 |   10 | A    | 2018 |            |          |
|  200 |   11 | B    | 2019 |            |          |
|  200 |   12 | C    | 2019 |            |          |
|  200 |   13 | D    | 2019 |            |          |
+------+------+------+------+------------+----------+
```

Please let me know if I can rephrase my question.

EDIT: if both `Identified` and `Multiple` columns are blank, then leave blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe can be built with the same types than this one (note for next time how you can provide a sample dataframe as one can't directly copy yours)

```
df= pd.DataFrame({
    'ID 1': [100]*4+[200]*4,
    'other_cols':range(8),
    'Identified':['12']+['']*7,
    'Multiple':['','multiple','multiple','']*2
})
print(df)
#    ID 1  other_cols  Identified  Multiple
# 0   100           0          12          
# 1   100           1              multiple
# 2   100           2              multiple
# 3   100           3                      
# 4   200           4                      
# 5   200           5              multiple
# 6   200           6              multiple
# 7   200           7
```

So to do the job, check where Identified if not equal (`ne`) to blank. `groupby.transform` with `any` to get True for all the same ID if one is not blank. Use the reverse (`~`) of this mask to select the IDs with only blank and assign blank in the other column.

```
# greate a mask with True where at least one non blank value per ID
mask = df['Identified'].ne('').groupby(df['ID 1']).transform(any)

# reverse the mask and assign blank 
df.loc[~mask, 'Multiple'] = ''

print(df)
#    ID 1  other_cols  Identified  Multiple
# 0   100           0          12          
# 1   100           1              multiple
# 2   100           2              multiple
# 3   100           3                      
# 4   200           4                      
# 5   200           5                      
# 6   200           6                      
# 7   200           7
```